# How to set Labels for Chart js Doughnut which has Multi Datasets

Tags: chart.js

[image]

I confused on set my chart labels which should initialize data from 2 different datasets. But as my chart picture above, the labels are mixed up.
The labels should initialize data like this:

> From Dataset1, label: 'Sinkronisasi' sync = 'Sudah Sinkronisasi',
> nonsync = 'Belum Sinkronisasi'
>
> From Dataset2, label: 'Statuses' S = 'Stop Container', P = 'Periksa
> Lanjut', PL = 'Periksa_Lanjut2', R = 'Rilis', BP = 'Batal Periksa', BS
> = 'Batal Stop'

Does anyone know how to set the labels like I mean?

Here my code:

```
createChartTPFT(S, P, PL, R, BP, BS, sync, nonsync) {
        /* CHART TRANSAKSI TPFT */
        const ctz = document.getElementById('donutChartTPFT');
        // const dataset1 = [sync, nonsync];
        // const dataset2 = [S, P, PL, R, BP, BS];
        const colors1 = ['sinkron', 'nonsinkron'];
        const colors2 = ['stop_container', 'periksa_lanjut', 'periksa_lanjut2', 'rilis', 'batal_periksa', 'batal_stop'];
        const cache = new Map();

        function colorGradient(context, c1, c2, c3) {
            const chartArea = context.chart.chartArea;
                if (!chartArea) {
                    return;
                }
            const chartWidth = chartArea.right - chartArea.left;
            const chartHeight = chartArea.bottom - chartArea.top;
                if (width !== chartWidth || height !== chartHeight) {
                    cache.clear();
                }
            let gradient = cache.get(c1 + c2 + c3);
                if (!gradient) {
                    width = chartWidth;
                    height = chartHeight;
                    const centerX = (chartArea.left + chartArea.right) / 2;
                    const centerY = (chartArea.top + chartArea.bottom) / 2;
                    const r = Math.min(
                        (chartArea.right - chartArea.left) / 2,
                        (chartArea.bottom - chartArea.top) / 2
                    );
                    const ctx = context.chart.ctx;
                    gradient = ctx.createRadialGradient(centerX, centerY, 0, centerX, centerY, r);
                    gradient.addColorStop(0, c1);
                    gradient.addColorStop(0.20, c2);
                    gradient.addColorStop(1, c3);
                    cache.set(c1 + c2 + c3, gradient);
                }
            return gradient;
        }

        const donutChartTPFT = new Chart(ctz, {
            type: 'doughnut',
            data: {
                labels: ['Stop Container', 'Periksa Lanjut', 'Periksa_Lanjut2', 'Rilis', 'Batal Periksa', 'Batal Stop', 'Sudah Sinkronisasi', 'Belum Sinkronisasi'],
                datasets: [
                    {
                        label: 'Sinkronisasi',
                        // data: dataset1,
                        data: [sync, nonsync],
                        backgroundColor: function(context) {
                            let c = colors1[context.dataIndex];
                            if (!c) {
                                return 'transparent';
                            }

                            if (c === 'sinkron') {
                                const start = "#6B75D0"; 
                                const mid = "#FFE4E2";
                                const end = "#E0473D";
                                return colorGradient(context, start, mid, end);
                            } else if (c === 'nonsinkron') {
                                const start2 = "#95D6F5";
                                const mid2 = "#E3EDFF";
                                const end2 = "#4C7BD3";
                                return colorGradient(context, start2, mid2, end2);
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Statuses',
                        // data: dataset2,
                        data: [S, P, PL, R, BP, BS],
                        backgroundColor: function(context) {
                            let c = colors2[context.dataIndex];
                            if (!c) {
                                return 'transparent';
                            }

                            if (c === 'stop_container') {
                                const start = "#6B75D0";
                                const mid = "#C3C9FC";
                                const end = "#5E6AD1";
                                return colorGradient(context, start, mid, end);
                            } else if (c === 'periksa_lanjut') {
                                const start2 = "#95D6F5";
                                const mid2 = "#D6F2FF";
                                const end2 = "#57B7E4";
                                return colorGradient(context, start2, mid2, end2);
                            } else if (c === 'periksa_lanjut2') {
                                const start3 = "#7DC7E9";
                                const mid3 = "#72FFF2";
                                const end3 = "#1DB6A8";
                                return colorGradient(context, start3, mid3, end3);
                            } else if (c === 'rilis') {
                                const start4 = "#68B744";
                                const mid4 = "#FFF1C2";
                                const end4 = "#F8C62F";
                                return colorGradient(context, start4, mid4, end4);
                            } else if (c === 'batal_periksa') {
                                const start5 = "#8D87FF";
                                const mid5 = "#FFB876";
                                const end5 = "#F58115";
                                return colorGradient(context, start5, mid5, end5);
                            } else if (c === 'batal_stop') {
                                const start6 = "#6697E6";
                                const mid6 = "#FFC6CD";
                                const end6 = "#EC5F70";
                                return colorGradient(context, start6, mid6, end6);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            options: {
                responsive: true,
                plugins: {
                    legend: {
                        display: true,
                        position: 'bottom',
                        padding: {
                            top: 2
                        },
                        labels: {
                            usePointStyle: true,
                            pointStyle: 'rectRounded',
                            font: {
                                size: 12,
                                family: "Open Sans",
                                style: "normal",
                                weight: 'bold'
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```